# CSS: Images width and height do not appear the same even though being set in the CSS

Tags: html, css

I am practicing making sites in pure HTLML and CSS. I have two muffin images here. In my CSS I set them both to the same width and height, but when I view the page in my browser, it appears that the muffin image on the right is slightly larger than the one on the left. Also the text below each muffin is conflicting.

[image]
How do I make it so the muffin images are the correct size?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Muffin Shoppe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Welcome to the Muffin Shoppe</h1>
      <h3>We are not gay; but by the taste of our muffins you would think we are!</h3>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div class="muffin-display" id="first">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Muffin_NIH.jpg" alt="A fresh blueberry muffin">
        <div class="muffin-text">
          <h3>A fresh blueberry muffin</h3>
          <p>Made by our German migrants in the back</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="muffin-display" id="second">
        <img src="http://www.dunbarsystems.com/Images/enlarge/blue-berry-muffin-enlarge(o9czf3).jpg" alt="Cancer Causer">
        <div class="muffin-text">
          <h3>The Cancer Causer!</h3>
          <p>We don't call this badboy the cancer causer for no reason</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url(pink.jpg);
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
}

.muffin-display img {
  width: 200px;
  height 200px;
}

.muffin-display p {

}

#first {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: typo mistake `.muffin-display img {
  width: 200px;
  height 200px;
}` edited `height: 200px;` add `:` between them

Comment: Just a minor (and off-topic) comment but: "*We don't call this badboy the cancer causer for no reason*" - I think this has to be the least appealing implementation of marketing I've ever read, carcinogens are not often known for their delicious, or appealing, nature.

Comment: @DavidThomas Haha, that's the point mate. Upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
.muffin-display img {
      width: 200px !important;
      height: 200px !important;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjatsr4z/

Comment: Is there a better way to select the #first and #second divs in section besides using id selector?

Comment: This will kill the image ratio unless they are a square (as seen in the jsfiddle). I really think that the solution comes from working better with the layout around the images (or working with images that are the size you need from scratch), rather than forcing the images to look like you want them to.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4, you can try with `section .muffin-display:first-child {  };`, and `section .muffin-display:last-child {  };`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define width and float for both containers. Also, if you define width and height as 200px, you expect the images to be perfect squares (and your example ones aren't), or to lose the ratio.

Either you define the width and give height:auto, or you pre-crop the images to the desired size before inserting them.

Try with this, just to begin with:

```
.muffin-display img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.muffin-display {
  width:300px;
  height:400px; 
  border:1px solid red; //always good to include a temporary border to see how things are getting positioned.
}

#first {
  float: left;
}

#second {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: That works. But floating it right makes my background image disappear

Comment: I just needed to add overflow: hidden; Thanks

Comment: After floating you need to use clear:both or overflow "hack" to avoid problems. See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Also, why do you need the margin-left: 350px on the #first? I don't think I understand.